# Is it possible to automatically generate highlights from a video using sound?

Tags: editing, audio, programming

I am looking to create an automatic highlight tool to generate highlights using sound, for example a sporting event would have an important part when there is a louder sound so, that part should be included in a highlights package.

I am presuming that this would be possible, but are there any APIs/libraries for any programming languages in which this would be ideal to develop?